# NDB - How to store properties on a model instance that are ignored by the datastore?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I am trying to store properties on a model instance of an `ndb.Model` class, so that they are ignored when writing to the datastore, but are pickled correctly so I can store in Memcache.

For example, I have the following model:-

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb

class TestModel(ndb.Model):
    lat = ndb.FloatProperty()
    lon = ndb.FloatProperty()

    def set_lat(self, lat):
        self.lat = lat

    def set_lon(self, lon):
        self.lon = lon

    def set_child(self, testModel):
        setattr(self, 'child', testModel)
```

I was hoping that I could store this in Memcache, and when I retrieve it all the member variables would be restored. But `child` is getting lost. For a test, see the following code.

```
    # create a model and assign some props
    testModel = test_model.TestModel()
    testModel.set_lat(55.55)
    testModel.set_lon(-0.565)
    testModel.set_child(test_model.TestModel())


    # store to memcache
    key = "test_model_key"
    memcache.set(key, testModel, 0)


    # get from memcache
    fromCacheModel = memcache.get(key)

    # here fromCacheModel.child does not exist??
```

The model retrieved from Memcache has no `child` property.

This works with `db.Model`, but not with `ndb.Model`. The reason I would like to do it, is so I can 
store fully formed objects in Memcache for quicker retrieval (less rpc calls).

Comment: You can use an expando model.

Comment: By the way. I remembered I used a property name without the _ in the past, which was not part of the model and could be used for this purpose. But ....

Comment: Overriding ____init____ in this way will cause problems, unless you understand how the ndb metaclass works (at least attempt to call super).  Try using names without the leading _  , and just use setattr inside a method to set a property value, rather than trying to override ____init____

Comment: You might also want to expand on what you are trying to in more detail. There maybe better ways of doing it.

Comment: Tim, yes overriding __init__ in this way fails with nbd.Model. I'm showing what I have done in db.Model in the past, and was asking how to transition this to ndb.Model

Comment: I have edited the question to give a clearer example of the problem

Comment: You may need to pickle the object yourself first.  The method to serialize the data, and it may in fact not be picking up your properties.  Try pickle/unpickle and see if it works without touching memcache, if it does then storing the pickle in memcache will work.

Comment: It pickles/unpickles fine if I don't extend ndb.Model. I.e. If I extend db.Model, or nothing all is fine. Do you know why I can't extend ndb.Model for such a simple object. Or a way to store attributes on a nbd.Model that don't get stored in the datastore, but do pickle as expected. Seems like a limitation to ndb if I can't do this.